# Feed Forward Neural Network Back Propogation Algorithm Assumption

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

During back propagation it appears that it's assumed that any error created in a hidden layer only affects one layer higher (for example see the derivation [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5740/2016sp/resources/backprop.pdf), specifically equation 16).

That is, when calculating `dE/dy_j` the derivation states it uses the chain rule, however it only differentiates over nodes with indices in `I_j` (i.e. only over nodes one layer higher than `y_j`). Why is it the case that higher layers are ignored in this calculation? We could take into account the `i+1` layer as well by considering that `x_{i+1} = \sum_i w_{i,i+1} f(\sum_{j} w_{j,i} y_j)` (which clearly has `y_j` dependence).

Comment: Fwiw I considered posting this on MSE, but I was afraid I would get an answer along the lines of 'yep that paper isn't using the chain rule correctly, can't help you any further' sort of thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher layers aren't being ignored. In equation 16, the `E` in the `dE/dy_i` is the error of the final output, so that gradient already includes effects of all subsequent layers. That's the whole point of backpropagation. You start with the error at the output and compute the gradient with respect to the previous layer. Then, you use that gradient to compute the gradient for the next previous layer, etc.

You could do what you are describing but it would make for a much more complicated formulation. A convenient/efficient aspect of the backpropagation formulation is that since you only need to use the error term for the subsequent layer, it doesn't matter whether you have a total of 3 layers or 4 or 50. You apply the same simple formula to each hidden layer, accumulating chain rule terms as you work your way backward through the network.

Comment: Ah so for example if we had a 4 layer network and labeled the layers as 0,1,2,3 (input, hidden, hidden, output) then calculating `dE/dy_1` we use the calculation for `dE/dy_2` that we just calculated previously which does take into account `dE/dy_3` implicitly (because of how it was calculated). Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. You start by computing `dE/dy_3`, which provides the data you then use to compute `dE/dy_2`. And `dE/dy_2` then has the data used to compute `dE/dy_1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clarification!